# Invalid Run Id After running drupal page using XHProf

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have installed the Drupal XHProf 7.x-1.0-beta2 module and enabled it on the Modules page of my site.

I have turned enabled the use of the module at Configuration -> Development -> XHProf settings (/admin/config/development/xhprof) by checking ON " Enable profiling of all page views and drush requests. "

Now what?

When I visit a page and click "XHProf output" at the bottom of the page, I get this error:

" Run #51b789ae8cea0: Invalid Run Id = 51b789ae8cea0 "

And the list of the "Top 100 functions" is totally empty. I am a bit lost as to what I should be seeing or where to go from here. Any help greatly appreciated.

please refer error screenshot

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can find some help there http://www.pixelite.co.nz/article/profiling-drupal-7-performance-xhprof-and-devel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your backend folder structure.create a folder named `xhprof` in your server, inside `tmp` folder in your server like 10.20.4.123/tmp

on clicking "XHProf output" at the bottom of the page.it will display output.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code that returns this error it's a file exists check. I changed $run_desc to output the full filename vs the run id.

```
if (!file_exists($file_name)) { 
  xhprof_error("Could not find file $file_name"); 
  $run_desc = "Invalid Run Id = $file_name"; 
  return null; 
}
```

In my case for a run id of *617064cfe0f71* it was looking for a filename formatted like

```
617064cfe0f71.xhprof.xhprof
```

The filename is derived from this function

```
private function file_name($run_id, $type) {
  $file = "$run_id.$type." . $this->suffix;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a permission issue，just set `chmod 777` for your `xhprof` output directory.